# iText7 AbstractITextEvent is only for internal usage

Tags: android, itext7

I am trying to create a new PDF file in the public Documents folder. iTex7 is launched directly from a Dialog created by an external library com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.

```
 lateinit var writer : PdfWriter

    path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).absolutePath

 val file = File(path + "/" + filename + ".pdf")

        if (!file.parentFile.exists()) file.parentFile.mkdirs()

    writer = PdfWriter(file)

  pdf = PdfDocument(writer)
```

Sometiems this leads to an error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AbstractITextEvent is only for internal usage.
       at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.AbstractITextEvent.<init>(AbstractITextEvent.java:52)
       at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.AbstractProductITextEvent.<init>(AbstractProductITextEvent.java:41)
       at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.AbstractContextBasedITextEvent.<init>(AbstractContextBasedITextEvent.java:43)
       at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.AbstractProductProcessITextEvent.<init>(AbstractProductProcessITextEvent.java:50)
       at com.itextpdf.kernel.actions.events.ITextCoreProductEvent.<init>(ITextCoreProductEvent.java:53)
       at com.itextpdf.kernel.actions.events.ITextCoreProductEvent.createProcessPdfEvent(ITextCoreProductEvent.java:69)
       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1947)
       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:273)
       at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:254)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.callbacks.DialogCallbackExtKt.invokeAll(DialogCallbackExtKt.java:68)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.onActionButtonClicked$core(MaterialDialog.java:406)
       at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.internal.button.DialogActionButtonLayout$onFinishInflate$1.onClick(DialogActionButtonLayout.kt:84)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
       at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Any help? Sorry I am a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Proguard then add a line to "proguard-rules.pro" (app module):

```
-keep public class com.itextpdf.**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue is that the ITEXT library doesn't work with .NET CORE. When I changed my project to .NET Framework 4.8.1 the error went away with no code changes.